# how to stop bots signing up without captcha or email verification

Tags: php, security, captcha, verification

I've seen a couple of websites (for instance - crowdrise.com) where it seems you can signup for an account and create pages on their website without once having to click a link in an email or having to type in a captcha at all.

So how do they go about doing that without having robots on their site creating profiles and pages?

Thanks :) Julia

Answer (score 3):

You can use javascript validation and also use cookie validation. Also you can only use purely javascript forms which will be invisible to bots. You can also use email verification, so even if you have a lot of signups by bots, unless they verify their email they cant use the accounts.

you can also limit the registration by applying limits per ip address, etc.

http://www.sitepoint.com/captcha-problems-alternatives/

Comment: Every method other than the email verification you mentioned can be broken by a bot.

Comment: well, even email verification can be broken by a bot (i know i can create a bot to do that), but we are talking about some simple bots here etc...

Answer (score 1):

If your using ASP.net you can use the NoBot control from the Ajax Control Toolkit as seen here:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/NoBot/NoBot.aspx

Otherwise I would use recaptcha or other service:

http://www.google.com/recaptcha

Both are free, easy to use and work well.

Limiting IP addresses will only cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty cool alternative to captchas http://parametercontraption.com/article/jquery-slidelock-plugin-tutorial/

Comment: The slider lock provides 0 protections against repeat attacks

Comment: She doesn't want to protect against attacks as i understand. The only way to avoid what you're asking for is using captchas.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [OpenID](http://openid.net/),  although all OpenID providers should be asking the use to solve a captcha.

Comment: What's to stop a spamhaus from operating their own OpenID provider?

Comment: @Henning Makholm You choose what openid providers you accept.  Google, Facebook, AOL, StackOverflow,  these are good choices.

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic captcha will help you, check out http://stackextra.skycity.co.za/t/923/stackextra-arithmetic-captcha-easy-and-strong.html

Comment: How is that not a captha?